# Analytical solution of $ax+by+cz+dw+... = n$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, diophantine-equations, multivariate-polynomial

Suppose I have a multivariate linear equation (of an arbitrary number of variables, for this example, say 4): $f(x,y,z,w) = ax+by+cz+dw=n$, where $a,b,c,d$ are constants that I know. And $n$ is the value that I want the LHS to equal (the target). Is there an analytical solution that gives me these values $x,y,z,w$. Or at least a parametric equation if it has multiple solutions?

**EDIT:** $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{N \cup {{0}}}$ AND $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N \cup {{0}}}$

Comment: Are there an restrictions on the variable values? If not, then you can just have all of the variables, except one with a non-zero coefficient, be parameters, with the remaining variable being defined in terms of the other variables by solving the equation for it. With your example, if $a \neq 0$, you can have $y,z,w$ be parameters with any values, and with $x = \frac{n - by - cz - dw}{a}$.

Comment: The restriction is that the numbers must be positive integers. And for my uses, I do not know any of the values so I cannot make a parametric equation like that.

Comment: coefficient $a,b,c,\cdots$ are also natural?

Comment: Precisely. I will add this to the post.

Comment: It is an arbitrary amount.

Comment: Your choice of notation could be improved. So, you would like to parameterize the solution set of $$a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \cdots + a_n x_n = b$$ over the integers, right? Well, positive integers.

Comment: The bit you told John Omielan about "I do not know any of the values so I cannot make a parametric equation like that" is pure nonsense. Without the restriction to positive integers, *every set of values for* $y,z,w$ that you can pick determines a solution, where $x$ is given by the formula. I.e., that formula is the parametric equation you asked for in your question. You have multiple solutions, and this is how you can find all of them.  Now the restriction to positive integers  presents some problems, but with certain exceptions, you will still have multiple solutions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  Ah.  I misunderstood the proposition. I thought that it meant that if you can find the first 3, you can find the fourth. I now know.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes indeed.

Comment: You have a hyperplane intersecting the positive orthant and then intersecting the integer lattice. There could be infinitely many solutions. There could be finitely many,  and one could enumerate them. The first step would be to neglect the intersection with the integer lattice and verify whether the other intersection produces a bounded polytope. If it does, the intersection with the integer lattice cannot produce infinitely many solutions.